# Disable scrolling in tableview while popup is opened

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created simple poUp in swift however I can't seem to find answer to "how to disable scrolling in `tableview` while popup is opened?". The problem is that if popUp is opened I do not want to scroll.

That is how I create the popUp inside `tableview` if button is tapped:

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name:  "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RatingViewController") as! RatingViewController
self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
```

I want it to be full screen and scrolling disabled but right now it is under navigationBar and scrolling is enabled.

I tried adding this line `tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false` but it does nothing.

To illustrate things:

[image]

Comment: `self.tbl_view.isScrollEnabled = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableView`inherits from `UIScrollView`. You can controll scrolling by setting [`isScrollEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619395-isscrollenabled).

Comment: Woww.. I actually didn't know that. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways. You can disable scrolling this way :

```
tableview.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Or you can put a transparent view behind PopUp View, making it the size of the screen. This way, users won't be able to touch table view anyway :)